# How do I debug properly using Eclipse and Pydev?

Tags: django, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I have got Pydev configured properly so it runs my app, however when I want to inspect/trace my code by setting up breakpoints the debugger does not kick in (can't trace). Does anyone got any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Do you call the debugger with the correct editor window selected (highlighted)? You should tell more about what you do. Python or Jython for example. Can you actually run any Pyhon code etc.

Comment: yes all python code works. 
First I set a breakpoint in a view, then I select manage.py, click debug and it runs fine. I then go to the url for that view but the breakpoint does not kick in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--noreload` option is crucial, otherwise server will fork and your breakpoint won't trigger.

Comment: Where's the --noreload option?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily you wouldn't have to select manage.py and hit debug. From your description it sounds like you may not have set up the Django launch params in the Run/Debug settings panel.

Here are some step by step instructions:

http://pydev.blogspot.com/2006/09/configuring-pydev-to-work-with-django.html

and

http://developeradventures.blogspot.com/2008/03/eclipse-django-debugging.html

The important part is adding the entry to the Run/Debug settings. When it's time to debug, set the breakpoint, on the Eclipse toolbar click on the Debug button's drop-down arrow and select the Django project you've defined. Then from a browser window go to your Django server's URL. Eclipse should stop at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I found what my problem was. I had to set the breakpoint on the def statement in views.py instead of the statements after it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're debugging the Django `runserver`, make certain you specify the `--noreload` command line parameter.  Otherwise the debugger ends up looking at the wrong python instance and never trips any breakpoints.