# why is supervisor starting TWO django servers?

Tags: django, supervisord

I'm running django with the djano-sslserver extension.  For some reason, when supervisor starts my django server, I'm getting TWO django servers (and they seem to be interfering with each other).

my command is

```
/path/to/virtualenv/python /path/to/manage.py runsslserver [many params] fully.qualified.domain.name:443
```

two funny things:

1) When I start supervisord (/etc/init.d/supervisord start), one of the Django processes is the child of the other.

2) If I stop supervisord (/etc/init.d/supervisord stop), only one of the two djangos stops.  the other survives

Comment: Can you open supervisorctl console and see number of django processes running.
`sudo supervisorctl` 
`status`

Comment: only one line, with one pid, returned, so I'm guessing that as far as supervisor is concerned, it thinks it is only running one process.

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843137/too-many-instances-are-running-for-django-server might explain. Recommended way of deploying to production is using uWSGI.